# How do I add a new ContentType using Feature Upgrading?

Tags: powershell, content-type, feature-upgrade

I have created a new Content Type. How do I publish it using `Update-SPSolution` and feature upgrading?

I added the following Code to my Feature Manifest:

```
<UpgradeActions>
   <VersionRange BeginVersion="1.0.0.3" EndVersion="1.0.0.4">
      <ApplyElementManifests>
         <ElementManifest Location="NewContentType\Elements.xml"/>
      </ApplyElementManifests>
      <CustomUpgradeAction Name="UpdateVersion"/>
   </VersionRange>
</UpgradeActions>
```

After `Feature.Upgrade(bool)` the ContentType is not installed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the previous version was 1.0.0.3 and NewContentType\Elements.xml contains the ContentType it should be ok.

If the previous version was anything by 1.0.0.3 upgrading won't do anything as your version range specifies 1.0.0.3 <= version < 1.0.0.4.